# Can you render videos on a server

Tags: video

I would like to create an app that combines videos and renders them on a server.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: I've been editing videos for around 20 years now, and I just started looking into this over the last few weeks.  The barrier to *editing* video remotely has always been latency.  But with technologies like Stadia around the corner, we'll see companies make inroads to cloud-hosted video editing soon, too.  Check out Google colab.  You get access to free compute time, including GPU up to a certain limit, and you can process files directly from Google Drive.  I'm learning Python, and it's pretty accessible.  JavaScript is also big.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Such a concept is often called "render farm".

On the server side you could use tools like ffmpeg that can concatenate videos. To call it you could build a dedicated render service which works like a job management agent (think of sth. like Jenkins). The goal is to decouple the render jobs from whatever service/API your app talks to.

Maybe you can even use Jenkins because it has a REST API that enables you to trigger builds. Instead of a classic build job, your job will combine videos. This approach might save you some time.

However that is just a recommendation, other architectures are possible.

On the client side, there is one possible problem to be aware: all the raw video material needs to be uploaded to the server and bandwidth or uplink speed could be a limiting factor at some point.

On the server side you have to watch out for possible DoS attack scenarios and upload of malicious content.